# How to trigger on click event to a button which is on a modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on an application and need to save modal content into an excel sheet. SO I have created a button 'Export to Excel' and trying to bind on click event . But I couldn't able to . I highly appreciate if any can help out

http://jsfiddle.net/czACy/1/

I have used the following code to trigger :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div[id^=modal]').on("show", function(){
        $('div[id^=modal] #excelImport').on('click', function(evt){
            //evt.stopPropagation();
           alert('hello'); 
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this? http://jsfiddle.net/kbypftgv/1/

i think you were too specific with your jquery event nesting

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div[id^=modal] #excelImport').on('click', function(evt){
        console.log('click');
        alert('hello'); 
    });
});
```